# How to get the property of stdClass php

Tags: php, object, stdclass

I want to get the property of [code]. To save in a variable $co=[code];
Any idea?

```
    stdClass Object
(
[errors] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [message] => Invalid or expired token
                [code] => 89
            )

    )

)
```

Comment: `$obj->errors[0]->code`. Google would have told you the same thing.

Comment: Agree, but the [0] made me to mess all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have dumped `$var`, you can get `[code]` by using `$var->errors[0]->code`